# how to implement the idea of dependent model fields in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an app that has Post and Tag as models

the post has tags, each tag describing the post somehow, for example
a post has the following tags

```
#backend_development #coding
```

and I am relating the Post model to the Tag model by a ManyToManyField

and each post creator chooses the tags from a pre-populated list from the database, meaning they don't create the tags on the post, they just choose them.

the thing is I am trying to classify those tags somehow, for example , to have all the tech related tags are under a tech field in the list when clicked it displays all the tech related tags, if it's a business field for example it displays all the business related tags

how can I implement this classification ? should I build another model called SubjectTag for example to include the subjects of all the tags and relate it with the Tag model?
should I not do that and use some kind of html magic that can do this trick for me ? I don't know , what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you want is classify the tags by types/subjects.

**Proposal 1:**
So, then what I will do is something to define an enum for instance for the available subjects:

`SUBJECTS = ("Business", "Tech", ...)`

Then in your models, as you said you will have the model `Post` which will have a M2M to the model `Tag`. Then your model Tag could contain a couple of fields: `name` and `subject`.

- `name` will be the name of the tag you can use to show to the client.
- `subject` will be an Enum type where the possible choices are the ones defined on the `SUBJECTS`. For instance in Postgresql you can define enums as you can see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-enum.html). Also, you can leave it as string field too and be more permissive, which then you can add free text on the `subject` field.

**Proposal 2:**
Define the subjects in a third model, and then your tags model will have a foreign key to the `Subject` model.

With the both proposals above, once you can this structure, then you always can filter/group the tags by subjects, and present it in the way you want to the end-user.

The pros of the **Proposal 2** is that allows you to add/remove subjects in a most flexible way. So, I think that's the best option.

Comment: but how can I present this relationship to the user, meaning how can i make the user choose the tech topic and automatically appear the tags related to it in the panel when creating a post?

Comment: what kind of technologies would I use ?

Answer (score 0):

A TagSubject model associated to tags (possibly many-to-many) would seem to be the most direct and manageable way to handle tag classification.